# filtering a large file with a large filter

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, performance, gnu-parallel

I want to extract all lines of `$file1` that start with a string stored in `$file2`.

`$file1` is 4 GB large with about 20 million lines, `$file2` has 2 million lines, is about 140 MB large and contains two columns separated with `,`. The maximal line length of both files is well below 1000, they are sorted with `LC_ALL=C` and `$file1` can contain any additional characters except `\0`.

Unexpectedly this command

```
parallel --pipepart -a $file1 grep -Ff $file2
```

consumes an extreme amount of memory and gets killed by the OS.

The command works if I limit the number of threads:

```
parallel --pipepart -j 8 -a $file1 grep -Ff $file2
```

For the last command, htop reveals that each `grep -Ff $file2`-thread constantly occupies 12.3 GB of memory. I assume this demand comes from the dictionary grep builds from `$file2`.

How can I achieve such a filter more efficiently?

Comment: You may want to split `$file2` up into smaller pieces and run multiple times over these patterns. Feeding two million patterns into `grep` is an _extremely_ suboptimal thing to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda Can I realize such a split with gnu parallel? I am using `-F` as I am looking for partial matches at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Kusalananda Why would it be suboptimal? I would argue: Splitting `$file2` only means reading in `$file1` multiple times potentially having more comparisons as grep may optimize its dictionary depending on the file after `-f`.

Comment: I mean, it's suboptimal in the sense that `grep` was never made for matching 2M strings from one file in another. If `$file1` has any form of structure that you could use, that would be beneficial. For example, you may only want to match against a particular column in a dataset, and only look for exact matches, well then `join` is a _much_ better tool.

Comment: The matches are from the beginning of the line until the second `,`. But there might be additional commata. `join` only uses one field and I am not sure what it does when the number of fields per line differs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is covered in `man parallel` https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Grepping-n-lines-for-m-regular-expressions

> **EXAMPLE: Grepping n lines for m regular expressions.**
>
> The simplest solution to grep a big file for a lot of regexps is:
>
> ```
> grep -f regexps.txt bigfile
> ```
>
> Or if the regexps are fixed strings:
>
> ```
> grep -F -f regexps.txt bigfile
> ```
>
> There are 3 limiting factors: CPU, RAM, and disk I/O.
>
> RAM is easy to measure: If the grep process takes up most of your free
>   memory (e.g. when running top), then RAM is a limiting factor.
>
> CPU is also easy to measure: If the grep takes >90% CPU in top, then
>   the CPU is a limiting factor, and parallelization will speed this up.
>
> It is harder to see if disk I/O is the limiting factor, and depending
>   on the disk system it may be faster or slower to parallelize. The only
>   way to know for certain is to test and measure.
>
> **Limiting factor: RAM**
>
> The normal grep -f regexs.txt bigfile works no matter the size of
>   bigfile, but if regexps.txt is so big it cannot fit into memory, then
>   you need to split this.
>
> grep -F takes around 100 bytes of RAM and grep takes about 500 bytes
>   of RAM per 1 byte of regexp. So if regexps.txt is 1% of your RAM, then
>   it may be too big.
>
> If you can convert your regexps into fixed strings do that. E.g. if
>   the lines you are looking for in bigfile all looks like:
>
> ```
> ID1 foo bar baz Identifier1 quux
> fubar ID2 foo bar baz Identifier2
> ```
>
> then your regexps.txt can be converted from:
>
> ```
> ID1.*Identifier1   
> ID2.*Identifier2
> ```
>
> into:
>
> ```
> ID1 foo bar baz Identifier1
> ID2 foo bar baz Identifier2
> ```
>
> This way you can use grep -F which takes around 80% less memory and is
>   much faster.
>
> If it still does not fit in memory you can do this:
>
> ```
> parallel --pipepart -a regexps.txt --block 1M grep -Ff - -n bigfile |
>   sort -un | perl -pe 's/^\d+://'
> ```
>
> The 1M should be your free memory divided by the number of CPU threads
>   and divided by 200 for grep -F and by 1000 for normal grep. On
>   GNU/Linux you can do:
>
> ```
> free=$(awk '/^((Swap)?Cached|MemFree|Buffers):/ { sum += $2 }
>           END { print sum }' /proc/meminfo)
> percpu=$((free / 200 / $(parallel --number-of-threads)))k
>
> parallel --pipepart -a regexps.txt --block $percpu --compress \
>   grep -F -f - -n bigfile |
>   sort -un | perl -pe 's/^\d+://'
> ```
>
> If you can live with duplicated lines and wrong order, it is faster to
>   do:
>
> ```
> parallel --pipepart -a regexps.txt --block $percpu --compress \
>   grep -F -f - bigfile
> ```
>
> **Limiting factor: CPU**
>
> If the CPU is the limiting factor parallelization should be done on
>   the regexps:
>
> ```
> cat regexp.txt | parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin --compress \
>   grep -f - -n bigfile |
>   sort -un | perl -pe 's/^\d+://'
> ```
>
> The command will start one grep per CPU and read bigfile one time per
>   CPU, but as that is done in parallel, all reads except the first will
>   be cached in RAM. Depending on the size of regexp.txt it may be faster
>   to use --block 10m instead of -L1000.
>
> Some storage systems perform better when reading multiple chunks in
>   parallel. This is true for some RAID systems and for some network file
>   systems. To parallelize the reading of bigfile:
>
> ```
> parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a bigfile -k --compress \
>   grep -f regexp.txt
> ```
>
> This will split bigfile into 100MB chunks and run grep on each of
>   these chunks. To parallelize both reading of bigfile and regexp.txt
>   combine the two using --fifo:
>
> ```
> parallel --pipepart --block 100M -a bigfile --fifo cat regexp.txt \
>   \| parallel --pipe -L1000 --round-robin grep -f - {}
> ```
>
> If a line matches multiple regexps, the line may be duplicated.
>
> **Bigger problem**
>
> If the problem is too big to be solved by this, you are probably ready
>   for Lucene.